Freerouting 1.9 as plugin on KiCad 8 not routing inner layers
I'm working on a 4 Layers PCB on KiCad 8.0 on MacOS the layers are set to be:

Signal
Power (GND)
Power (VCC)
Signal

Once the placing of the components has been completed I have tried to autoroute it using Freerouting version 1.9 installed using the plugin manager on KiCad itself. The result is that the autorouter is ignoring the 2 inner layers and tries to route GND and VCC using surface tracks rather than vias to the underneath layers.
I have tried the following:

Exporting the DNS session file to the same Freerouting but executed externally (downloaded from the old website) and it works properly routing through the inner layers as well (but it is much slower and buggy)

Changing the Layer setup to



Signal

Mixed (GND)

Mixed (VCC)

Signal
and it does route the GND and VCC lines through vias to the relative layers but now it also allows signals to be routed there.



Re installed everything (KiCad, plugins, Java, etc...) with no luck

Have you already faced this issue?
Thanks

Just a quick confirmation: did you put planes down on the middle layers and set the planes to the correct net, beyond naming the layers the node makes in the board settings, and then build the planes once with Ctrl+b?

Correct, the planes are created, filled and connected to the proper corresponding Net
